# Check if messages are published on a topic

Tags: ros, node, topic, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to check in my c++ code, if a message has been pusblished onto a certain topic. Is it possible to do this with basic ROS functions? If not, what would you advise to do?
Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/237789/check-if-messages-are-published-on-a-topic/) by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on ROS Answers with karma: 167 on 2016-06-22

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could subscribe to the topic (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber(c%2B%2B)#roscpp_tutorials.2BAC8-Tutorials.2BAC8-WritingPublisherSubscriber.Writing_the_Subscriber_Node).

---

*EDIT*

If you subscribe to the topic, the respective callback will be called every time a message is sent on this topic. If not, it will not be called. Then you can do what you want with the respective result.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2016-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on 2016-06-23**:
I would like to check if messages are published at all, I don't need to know the message. It is a topic from an actionserver, but I need to check without writing a client/

**Comment by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on 2016-06-23**:
Right... of course, I will give this a shot and report back.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-23**:
You will receive the messages content, but just ignore that. I don't think that there is another way...

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2016-06-23**:
mig is right, there is no other way. From the command line, you can call `rostopic hz <topic name>`, but that command is also implemented by subscribing to the topic and throwing away the message contents.

**Comment by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on 2016-06-23**:
Yes is it working as I want it to, thanks!

**Comment by [Hunterx](https://answers.ros.org/users/36662/hunterx/) on 2018-07-26**:
@Laurens Verhulst
May I ask how did you do that

**Comment by [-LD-](https://answers.ros.org/users/35853/-ld-/) on 2018-10-10**:
just write a subscriber (like in the tutorial) that hooks on the topic you are interested in. Then, once the callback gets called just store the time (inside the callback -> ros::Time callback_time = ros::Time::now();). In the main program check if the time has changed.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can open a terminal window while the node is running and enter the command `rostopic echo <topic name>`. If data is being published to the topic it will now show up in the terminal window.

[Here](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic) is a list of the rostopic commands for future reference.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2016-06-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-23**:
He asked how to check from C++ code. Other than that, you are right.

**Comment by [Laurens Verhulst](https://answers.ros.org/users/26924/laurens-verhulst/) on 2016-06-23**:
I would like to check in C++ code indeed. Additionally I want check whether messages are published at all.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2016-06-23**:
see edit in my answer.